Adding a 24-hour timer for each item added to a cart
I'm trying to add a 24-hour time limit for each item added to a cart. I want the items removed from the cart after the time expires.
const isExpired = (timestamp) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return now - timestamp > oneDay;
};
 
const removeExpiredItems = () => {  
    for (let productId in cart) {
        if (isExpired(cart[productId].addedAt)) {
            delete cart[productId];
        }
    }
};


The effect of adding an item to a cart and then removing it after 24 hours can be achieved by doing something like this:
let cart = [];

function addItem(naem) {
    let item = {
        id: "item" + cart.length, // in production use something good
        name: name,
        created: Date.now()
    }
    cart.push(item);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (Date.now() - item.created >= 86400000 && cart.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
            cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
            clearInterval(interval);
        } // else item doesnt exist or the 24 hours has not passed yet
    }, 1000);
};

addItem("this item will only exist for 24 hours.");

This code above creates a function called addItem which takes in a name of the item to be added.
I hope this helps.
